# Reusing FileInputStream

Tags: java, image, javafx, h2, fileinputstream

for a university project im supposed to program a database that saves a picture in a h2 database and shows it in an ImageView.

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(f);

Horse h = getSelectedHorse();
h.setImage(fileStream);
Connection c = H2ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
JdbcHorseDao horseDao = new JdbcHorseDao(c);
horseDao.update(h);
c.commit();


Image img = new Image(fileStream);
horseImages.put(h, img);
imageView.setImage(img);
```

When I save the image to the database first i can't immediately show it in the imageviewer and vice versa (when I show it first I can't save it to the database)

My thought's are that the stream is at the end of the file but I can't find out how to reposition the stream ( there is no seek() method)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to reopen the stream. There are [random access classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) that allow you to move to a certain position in a file, but you will incur a performance penalty. Also, you will be doing double reading in itself.

I think it is better to read the data from stream into byte[] and then reuse it for both operations.

Comment: hm 5 minutes after posting this i came to the same conclusion .. d'oh.

thanks!